# Get max key of Map<K,V> using lambda

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, max, java-8

I have a `Map<Float, String>` and would like to get the maximum of all keys. In C# I would do something like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<float, string>{{5,"foo"}, {42, "bar"}, {0, "foobarz"}};
float max = dictionary.Max(x => x.Key); //42
```

Now I'm looking for a way to do the same using Java 8 lambdas, but the closest I got is:

```
float max = (float)map.keySet().stream().mapToDouble((x) -> x).summaryStatistics().getMax();
```

This looks awful and requires completely unnecessary type casts. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The interface `Stream` contains the method `max` to get the maximum element. You can use a method reference as `Comparator`. The method `max` returns an `Optional<Float>`, because there is no maximum element in an empty stream. You can use the method `orElse` to provide an alternative value for this case.

```
float max = map.keySet().stream().max(Float::compareTo).orElse(0.0f);
```

Comment: `Float` contains also `compare(x,y)` so you can also use `Float::compare`

Comment: @Pshemo: True. However, `compare` uses primitive types whereas `compareTo` uses the wrapper types. In this case, I prefer the latter, because the code is already working with wrapper types (i.e. avoid boxing/unboxing).

Comment: OK, I see your point. Unboxing means `Float.compare(foo.floatValue(), bar.floatValue())` while `foo.compareTo(bar)` returns `Float.compare(this.value, bar.value)`. It means that in first case we are invoking `floatValue()` twice to get `value` while in second case we can skip it because we have direct access to `value`. Thanks, I learned something new today :)

Comment: @nosid Do you think there would be any performance difference in practice? I would expect that the calls of `floatValue()` would be inlined, resulting in the same code once it has been JIT'd.

Comment: @MauriceNaftalin: No, I don't think performance is an issue. I think it is good style not to introduce unnecessary, implicit type conversions.

Answer (score 14):

There's a more direct solution than operating on the keySet(); operate directly on the entrySet() using the comparator factories added to `Map.Entry`.

```
Map.Entry<K,V> maxElt = map.entrySet().stream()
                           .max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                           .orElse(...);
```

This permits not only getting min/max elements, but also sorting, so its easy to find the top ten key/value pairs like this:

```
Stream<Map.Entry<K,V>> topTen = map.entrySet().stream()
                                   .sorted(Map.Entry.byKeyComparator().reversed())
                                   .limit(10);
```